# Was David who he claimed to be?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-guest

In the tense thriller [The Guest](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2980592/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), David appears at a family home claiming to be an ex soldier and colleague of the family's dead son Caleb. The family has a photograph of the military unit which appears to validate David's story as someone resembling him is in the picture alongside Caleb.

But later events in the movie, including the military denying that anyone with his identity is still alive, cast doubt on his story. Also, David tries to destroy any witnesses who could identify him despite having told them who he claimed to be.

Was David who he claimed to be?

Comment: Related: [Why did David choose to ingratiate himself into Caleb's family?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/29961/49)

Answer (score 2):

David was, in actuality, an American soldier and friends with Caleb. There was a reason he sought shelter in the Petersons' home.

However, he was also part of a top-secret military experiment that turned men into weapons of war but also sociopathic killers if their identity was threatened.

So, in summation, David was:
1) a soldier
2) a friend of Caleb's
3) a ruthless killing machine 
4) invincible? (end scene)

Answer (score -4):

David did knew a plastic surgeon willing to do change his identity, they don't come easy, so where from did he knew him? Probably from the past, when he first got a facial reconstruction. Also, David said that he didn't need new dental, just a new face, probably because his dental was already "new" and so, off the grig. I'm in for David being Caleb and also a cyborg.